# How to call a RESTful API (ASP.NET) from Android App?

Tags: android, asp.net, json, rest

I followed the tutorial here: http://www.tutecentral.com/restful-api-for-android-part-1/ to create a RESTful API using ASP.NET and all is well. At the end of the tutorial I downloaded a ZIP file which contains a Java file with calls to the methods from the API.

Question is...how do I call these methods so they interact with my web service API? I'm really confused, I have done similar things in the past using PHP on my web server and inserting/extracting SQL data but never with ASP.NET or a setup similar to this.

If it helps, here are the contents of the Java file I get at the end of that tutorial:

```
public class RestAPI {
private final String urlString = "http://localhost:53749/Gen_Handler.ashx";

private static String convertStreamToUTF8String(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    String result = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        int readChars = 0;
        while (readChars != -1) {
            readChars = reader.read(buffer);
            if (readChars > 0)
               sb.append(buffer, 0, readChars);
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private String load(String contents) throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    w.write(contents);
    w.flush();
    InputStream istream = conn.getInputStream();
    String result = convertStreamToUTF8String(istream);
    return result;
}

private Object mapObject(Object o) {
    Object finalValue = null;
    if (o.getClass() == String.class) {
        finalValue = o;
    }
    else if (Number.class.isInstance(o)) {
        finalValue = String.valueOf(o);
    } else if (Date.class.isInstance(o)) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", new Locale("en", "USA"));
        finalValue = sdf.format((Date)o);
    }
    else if (Collection.class.isInstance(o)) {
        Collection<?> col = (Collection<?>) o;
        JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray();
        for (Object item : col) {
            jarray.put(mapObject(item));
        }
        finalValue = jarray;
    } else {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Method[] methods = o.getClass().getMethods();
        for (Method method : methods) {
            if (method.getDeclaringClass() == o.getClass()
                    && method.getModifiers() == Modifier.PUBLIC
                    && method.getName().startsWith("get")) {
                String key = method.getName().substring(3);
                try {
                    Object obj = method.invoke(o, null);
                    Object value = mapObject(obj);
                    map.put(key, value);
                    finalValue = new JSONObject(map);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return finalValue;
}

public JSONObject CreateNewAccount(String firstName,String lastName,String userName,String password) throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","RestAPI");
    o.put("method", "CreateNewAccount");
    p.put("firstName",mapObject(firstName));
    p.put("lastName",mapObject(lastName));
    p.put("userName",mapObject(userName));
    p.put("password",mapObject(password));
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}

public JSONObject GetUserDetails(String userName) throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","RestAPI");
    o.put("method", "GetUserDetails");
    p.put("userName",mapObject(userName));
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}

public JSONObject UserAuthentication(String userName,String passsword) throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","RestAPI");
    o.put("method", "UserAuthentication");
    p.put("userName",mapObject(userName));
    p.put("passsword",mapObject(passsword));
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}

public JSONObject GetDepartmentDetails() throws Exception {
    JSONObject result = null;
    JSONObject o = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject p = new JSONObject();
    o.put("interface","RestAPI");
    o.put("method", "GetDepartmentDetails");
    o.put("parameters", p);
    String s = o.toString();
    String r = load(s);
    result = new JSONObject(r);
    return result;
}
}
```

In my activity/fragment I tried doing this, but nothing is returned :(.

```
public void displaySafeMessage(View view) {
        RestAPI test = new RestAPI();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

        try {
            //jsonObj = test.CreateNewAccount("tudor","hofnar","tudor.hofnar","password");
            jsonObj = test.GetDepartmentDetails();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        String tmp = jsonObj.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), tmp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Note: the displaySafeMessage() method is called from a button onClick() which I did not include.There are no errors in Android with this code but also nothing is returned, and I have values in the Departments table, as a SQL query shows.

I know I'm missing a major thing here, so please let me know what it is!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the method in AsycTask class. Change the urlString  value to  `"http://10.0.2.2:53749/Gen_Handler.ashx";` to access it through a emulator. To access the API through the real android device you need to host the API in a public hosting space.

Answer (score 0):

use below code to call .net restful webservice

```
import android.content.Context;

import com.ayconsultancy.sumeshmedicals.R;
import com.ayconsultancy.sumeshmedicals.utils.Utils;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Admin33 on 30-12-2015.
 */
public class RestClient {
    //  static String ip = "http://192.168.1.220/SmartCure/api/";
    static Context context;
    private static int responseCode;
    private static String response;

    public static String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public static void setResponse(String response) {
        RestClient.response = response;
    }

    public static int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public static void setResponseCode(int responseCode) {
        RestClient.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public static void Execute(String requestMethod, String jsonData, String urlMethod, Context contextTemp, HashMap<String, Object> params) {
        try {
            context = contextTemp;
            String ip = context.getResources().getString(R.string.ip);
            StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder(ip + urlMethod);
            if (params != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> para : params.entrySet()) {
                    if (para.getValue() instanceof Long) {
                        urlString.append("?" + para.getKey() + "=" +(Long)para.getValue());
                    }
                    if (para.getValue() instanceof String) {
                        urlString.append("?" + para.getKey() + "=" +String.valueOf(para.getValue()));
                    }
                }
            }

            URL url = new URL(urlString.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /*milliseconds*/);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);


            switch (requestMethod) {
                case "POST" : case "PUT":
                    conn.setDoInput(true);
                    conn.setDoOutput(true);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                    conn.connect();
                    OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    os.write(jsonData.getBytes());
                    os.flush();
                    responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    System.out.println("GET Response Code :: " + responseCode);
                    break;


            }
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // success
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
                String inputLine;
                StringBuffer tempResponse = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    tempResponse.append(inputLine);
                }
                in.close();
                response = tempResponse.toString();
                System.out.println(response.toString());
            } else {
                System.out.println("GET request not worked");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```